# My image on HTML won't show only a blue question mark box

Tags: html, image, file, web, jpeg

Im learning HTML so I'm fairly new, I've been searching the web and haven't found a solution, it might be a minor error something I'm missing.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <title>Andis Place</title>

</head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

    <body>

<h1> <center> <font color=“Blue> Welcome to Andis Place</font>
</center> </h1>

<p> <font color=“Orange>Check out my different social media accounts down below and feel free to follow</font></p>


 <a href=“https://twitter.com”> Andis twitter</a>


 <a href=“https://www.instagram.com/andygonza_lez/?hl=en”> Andis Instagram</a> 


 <a href=“https://m.facebook.com/“> Andis Facebook</a>

<h1><a href=“”> <center> SHOP </center><a/> </h1>

<img src=“http://raulperez.tieneblog.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/tux.jpg”/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your quotes around your img src are smart quotes. Use a normal text editor and it should fix it. When writing quotes in some text editors such as Macs default text edit it auto replaces it to different style quotes.

View [this](http://www.iclarified.com/38772/how-to-disable-curly-quotes-in-mac-os-x-mavericks) article for more details about how to disable it if you wish to stick with using text edit.

Also here are some good text editors to use to avoid having this issue:

[Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com)

[Atom](https://atom.io)

[Brackets](http://brackets.io)

Comment: wow thank you appreciate it! First time seeing this solution while searching google.  I followed the article to disable it, I'm planning on trying those text editors you have recommended.

Comment: No problem!! Glad I could help. Don't feel obligated but if you feel like this helped answer your question and you want to for other users sake please accept the answer. Just so if other users have the same issue they will be able to find it and such. But either way just glad to help!! :)